# $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{k} \equiv 0 \ [p]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Here's the expression :

$\frac{(p-1)!}{1}+\frac{(p-1)!}{2}...+\frac{(p-1)!}{p-1}= (p-1)\times...\times2+(p-1)\times...\times1+...+(p-2)\times...\times1=q$.

For $p=5$ we obtain : $(4.3.2)+(4.3.1)+(4.2.1)+(3.2.1)=50$

I precise that $q\in \mathbb{N}^*$, and $p\ge 3$ a prime number.

We know that there are $(p-2)$ terms of each $k\in\{1,...,p-1\}$

$p$ divides $q$ ?

I don't search for a polynomial method or an arrangement of the coefficients. Just by developing is it possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $$=(p-1)!\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\dfrac1r?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee not this one and neither $(p-2) \Pi_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{(p-1)!}{i}$

Comment: @Maman Your expression is not clearly defined.  labbhattacharjee is just trying to guess what you mean.  In fact his suggestion is the only reasonable fit for the current description, so if you deny that then your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @ErickWong I precised that $p$ must appear...

Comment: @Maman your question is very hard to understand. What do you mean $p$ must appear? It looks like you are summing up things such that each is a multiplication of $p-2$ terms. But the number of summands you have and their pattern is far from being clear. Give us an example of your formula when $p$ is a small number like $p=5$?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  As the comments make clear, nobody can understand your formula.  Perhaps it will help if you write it out in full for a particular $p$, perhaps $p=5$?

Comment: Ok, I have a guess as to what is being asked.  Wilson's Theorem, and a little work, shows that $F(p)=(p-1)!\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac 1i\equiv 0 \pmod p$.  I am guessing that the OP wants to ask "is there a reasonably simple expression for the quotient $\frac {F(p)}p$?"

Comment: @lulu You guess it right !

Comment: Ok.  Could you edit the question to reflect that?  Also:  it might help if you wrote out the quotient for the first few primes.  It's not obvious to me that there is a good formula here...maybe seeing the first few would suggest something.

Comment: @lulu here it is for $p=5$

Comment: Well, I suggested doing several primes to see if there was a visible pattern.  I did the first few primes.  letting $Q(p)$ denote the quotient I get $Q(3)=1$, $Q(5)=10$, $Q(7)=252$, $Q(11)=966240$, $Q(13)=9528480$ (trusting that no error has been made).  that doesn't suggest much to me...but perhaps someone else sees something?

Comment: @lulu How do you want to apply Wilson's theorem ?

Comment: There is no need to develop anything, the key is $\frac{(p-1)!}{k} \not\equiv \frac{(p-1)!}{\ell} \pmod p$ for distinct $k, \ell \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,p-1 \}$.

Comment: @achillehui how to conclude then ?

Comment: $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p\implies \frac {(p-1)!}k\equiv -k^{-1} \pmod p$ for any non-zero residue $k$.Thus your sum is congruent to $-\sum k^{-1}$ but that's just the minus the sum of the residues which, for any odd prime, is $0 \pmod p$.

Comment: Why is it still [closed] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

For distinct $k, \ell \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, p-1 \}$, we have

$$\frac{(p-1)!}{k} - \frac{(p-1)!}{\ell} = \frac{(p-1)!}{k\ell}(k - \ell)\tag{*1}$$
The first factor is a product of numbers relative prime to $p$. The second factor $k - \ell$ is a number with $0 < |k - \ell| < p$.  So RHS and hence LHS of $(*1)$ is relative prime to $p$. This means

$$\frac{(p-1)!}{k} \not\equiv \frac{(p-1)!}{\ell} \pmod p \quad\text{ for distinct }\quad k, \ell \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,p-1 \}$$

So under modulus $p$ arithmetic,
$\frac{(p-1)!}{k}$ is simply a relabeling of the $p-1$ equivalent classes of integers relative prime to $p$. As a result,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{k} \equiv \sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1} \ell = \frac{p(p-1)}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

**Method 2**
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-1)!}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left[\frac{(p-1)!}{k} + \frac{(p-1)!}{p-k}\right]
= \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{(p-1)!}{k(p-k)}((p-k) + k)\\
= \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{p!}{k(p-k)}
= p \left[ \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{(p-1)!}{k(p-k)}\right]\tag{*2}
$$

Notice for each $1 \le k \le \frac{p-1}{2}$, $\displaystyle\;\frac{(p-1)!}{k(p-k)} = \prod_{\ell = 1, \ne k, p-k}^{p-1} \ell$ is a product of integer, so it is an integer.
This implies the sum in the square bracket on RHS of $(*2)$ is an integer. 
As a result, RHS and hence LHS of $(*2)$ is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: Thank you ! I like method 2

Comment: But how do you obtain $p!$ at the numerator ? Moreover $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{(p-1)!}{k(p-k)}$ must be an integer ?

Comment: @Maman see update of answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apply Wilson's Theorem:  $$(p-1)!\equiv -1 \pmod p\implies \frac {(p-1)!}k\equiv -k^{-1} \pmod p$$  For any non-zero residue $p$.

Thus the desired sum is just $$-\sum_{l=1}^{p-1}k^{-1}$$  But, up to sign, that's just the sum of the residues (as no two residues have the same inverse).  As $p$ is odd, the sum of the residues $\pmod p$ is $0$.

As a side note, [OEIS A007619](https://oeis.org/A007619) gives the sequence of "Wilson's quotients", i.e. $\frac {(p-1)!+1}p$ for primes $p$. There is no reference there to any alternate expression for them.  Doesn't prove there isn't a simple expression which gives them, of course, nor does it prove that there isn't a simple expression for your quotient.